# How to send the key to JavaScript?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to send image src to browser with AJAX.

Server side:

```
que = db.Query(Imageitem).order('-created')
item_list = que.fetch(limit=1)
if(len(item_list)>0):
    itemkey = {'imgid':item_list[0].key()}
else:
    itemkey = {'imgid':''}
json_itemkey = gaejsonEncoder.encode(itemkey)
```

Client side template:

```
<img src='img?img_id=$(.imgid)'></img>
```

I use [SNBinder](https://github.com/snakajima/SNBinder) for client side binding and $(.imgid) means itemkey[0].imgid.

But this is error.

```
datastore_types.Key.from_path(u'Imageitem', 515L, _app=u'fileshare')
is not JSON serializable
```

Is there any way to send the key for datastore entity to client side?

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to JSON encode a key item, just use the string version of the key by passing the key to str():

```
itemkey = {'imgid': str(item_list[0].key())}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to convert string to key?

Comment: Pretty sure all methods that expect a Key object [also accept the string](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html#Model_get) version.

Comment: imgitem = db.get(self.request.get("img_id")).This is error;BadKeyError: Invalid string key undefined===. How can I use "img_id"? Sorry.

Comment: @Yugo Kamo, you can either use ImageModel.get_by_id(img_id) or db.get(db.Key.from_path('ImageModel',img_id))

Comment: If you use @can's method you will need to use `item_list[0].key().id()` in the JSON

Comment: @Chris Farmiloe,@Can Basicil, Thank you very much. I've solved this problem in your both ways. I made some mistakes in binding. I really appreciate your kindness!

Answer (score 0):

Im my case I didn't need the key so I used a class extended from json.JSONEncoder to catch the Key instances of said db.Model.

```
import json
from datetime import datetime
from google.appengine.ext.db import Key

class ComplexEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self,obj):
        if isinstance(obj,datetime):
            return obj.isoformat()
        if isinstance(obj,Key):
            return ''
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self,obj)
```